# Few questions on GTA5 completion

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Relatively need to gaming. Recently bought a PS4 and have been playing GTA for a few weeks now. I have unlocked 3 characters (Franklin, Trevor and Micheal). Just had a quick question about the gameplay

- I'm just trying to complete as many missions as i can. Is that the whole objective? Meaning, keep completing missions to eventually reach the final mission?
- Often times i find myself driving around (sometimes long distances) to look for missions. I tend to just follow '?' (of the characters color) or maybe just drive to the safe-house of the character. Sometimes if i've been driving around for too long i simply switch characters. Is there a quicker way to find missions?
- Is there a way to see how far i have progressed in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time In Grand Theft Auto games completing one mission will then unlock another one. Often you will have several different missions available to you. In GTA V, there are three characters that all have access to their own missions (sometimes missions are available to more than one character if the story permits it).

To answer your first question, yes, in order to get to the final mission your goal is to continue to complete any available missions to progress the story.

If you don't have any missions available on the character you're currently playing, then change character and see if they have any available. If there are no missions available for any character, then completing Strangers & Freaks encounters (Side Missions) can often unlock new story missions. The Strangers & Freaks encounters are the Question marks you mentioned.

To address your final question, you can see your in game stats such as missions completed, percentage completed etc by going into the start menu and finding the stats tab. Alternatively, if you link your Rockstar Social Club account, you can find a handy 100% checklist, as well as more in depth stats on their social club website.